# Learning New Skills and Keeping Up to Date: Advice on Memory Retention

Tags: memory

I'm having a difficult time retaining the programming skills I'm actively trying to learn in an effort to apply for a junior developer position.

What I'm finding is that I can easily master isolated topics (for example, details about how Java's Container classes work and the different ways to sort a given container), but I find that when I move on to new topics I forget maybe 80% of what I learned (a few months down the road).

Sure, with good notes, I can get back up to speed much more quickly, but my question to those of you who are already in the professional field - is this common (this constant need to re-learn things you once felt you'd never forget)? If so, how do you get around it?  Should I accept that I'll probably only be an expert in the narrow domain that I currently use on a day to day basis?

Comment: Voting to close as this is not about programming as defined by the [help].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, and might be appropriate for a different exchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My father always said:

> You don't need to know everything, you
>   only need to know where to look it up

(roughly translated).

Going with your example, if you find you need to sort a collection very often you will remember after you've done it a few times, if you don't do it for a long time you will forget it again. That's perfectly normal imo.

So what I'm trying to say is there is no point in knowing stuff off the top of your head if you don't use it anyway as long as you know where you can look it up if you need it again.
I hope that made sense.

Comment: +1 With Google 1 click away, there's very little reason to know everything in detail, you just need to know the basic idea about as much as you can and Google for the specifics as you actually need them.